# Firefox does not load Vimeo player as it is insecure

Tags: firefox, vimeo, hsts

I have the Vimeo player embedded in my web application.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/1234" width="560" height="350" frameborder="0"
        webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

When I open the application from the production environment, the video will not load. Firefox states that vimeo.com is not safe and that my website requires HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS).

Does Vimeo support HSTS or is this planned? I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Answer (score -1):

check this, maybe will help you:
https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:112861
https://vimeo.com/forums/topic:109838

Comment: This seems to be completely unrelated to the question asked.